# Matplotlib confused sub-pixel resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a narrow peak that contains several thousand data points, additionally I want to draw a vertical line marking the peak.  I'm using Python 2.7 and Matplotlib 1.3.1 on Win7 (checked on two separate PCs).

For example, here is a Gaussian centred on sqrt(2) with its peak marked in red:

```
plt.plot(-arange(-4,4,1e-5)+sqrt(2), exp(-arange(-4,4,1e-5)**2)*0.92,'k',
         [sqrt(2),sqrt(2)],[0,1],'r')
```

[image: matplotlib zoom issue]

When the plot is wide enough you won't notice that anything is wrong, but as you make the plot narrower you will start to see that the red line sits to the right of the peak.  By taking a screenshot and zooming in on the pixels you can see that the line is exactly one pixel off where it should be. (The image above shows the peak enlarged with and without the red line so as to make it clear that the line has missed the peak.)

Am I being stupid or is this a bug?  If it's a bug presumably only one of the two lines is wrong: black or red?

Worrying about single pixels might sound pedantic, but your eye is actually surprisingly good at doing sub-pixel interpolation and can easily spot the problem.

Comment: When plotting this I can't re-create your problem. Though that might be because I defined `x` and `y` appropriately. I think it might be something to do with you plotting `-arange(-4,4,1e-5)+sqrt(2)` in your x-axis.

Comment: @Ffisegydd Using OP's plotting command, I also can **not** reproduce the problem. We might be able to narrow it down to a backend - I'm using the default configurations for Ubuntu 14.1. As a note to OP, try using different backends to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: @Ffisegydd - what do you mean by "appropriately"? I'm reasonably sure that it's not the data that's the problem because you can actually watch the red line moving relative to the black line as you make the plot narrower.

Comment: @Hooked - Just tried with wx, Qt and Tkinter and saw the same result in all three cases (I'm using ipython within Spyder).

Comment: @dan-man it might be useful to know the OS you are on too.

Comment: Win7 (I did mention it in the question)